# Keep GDM from printing password to console?

Tags: login, password, login-screen, gdm

Whenever I login with GDM, it prints my password to the console, and when logging out it is visible temporarily until GDM loads again. I would like to  disable this (assuming it's supposed to do this and it isn't a bug), as I don't want people seeing my password when I'm out in public.

Comment: It isn't supposed to do that, and it is a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1767918

Comment: Also see other linked bug - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1803993 .